# Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 - PHP 5.4.14 confirmed

Tags: php, input, namespaces, cron, ascii

hope you to help me....

here is the think I'm getting error from my host cronjob:

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in  /home/u599693672/public_html/app/cronjobs/bf3stats.php on line 11

this line specifically represents this part

```
$memberObj = new \app\classes\Members();
```

note that I'm using namespace, my hostserver is current using the 5.4.14 as you can see by the link http://vengeanceofwar.pusku.com/phpinfo

I really dont know where to find it anymore?? can be the cron job has a different php version than my web page?? if you need more information pls let me know

Comment: Just execute command line `php -v` from the account that the cron runs at

Comment: The version that the web server is running is not necessarily the same as the one that the shell runs. Like Mark said, `php -v` will show what's actually running, and for cron scripts you should explicitly state `/path/to/php-5.4` in the command.

Comment: thanks guys for the comment, think in life made me migrate the technology, but I thx your effort